# Rails jquery.tagsinput.js not executing after link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, callback, jquery-tags-input

### Problem

I have a custom effect from a file **jquery.tagsinput** that does not work after clicking on a link, while it will be fixed if I **refresh** the page.

### Tested Solutions

I tried the following:

1. Disabling turbolinks
2. Serching the file for ready or onload js functions - none was present

### Description

The file `jquery.tagsinput` has the following structure

```
(function($) {
   // Different functions and javascript staff
 })(jQuery);
```

The function includes different javascript functions that i need to be executed, they work if i refresh the browser. for ex.

```
$.fn.tagsInput = function(options) { 
   // Some code
 },options);
```

If I refresh the browser, I can see that the related html input field has two event handlers:

1. In `jquery.tagsinput`

   ```
       $(data.holder).bind('click',data,function(event) {
           $(event.data.fake_input).focus();
       });
   ```
2. In `jquery.js`

   ```
   if ( !( eventHandle = elemData.handle ) ) { 
   // Some Code    
   };
   ```
3. My `edit.html.erb` View

   ```
   <%= f.text_field :skill_list, :class => "tagsinput form-control", :id => "tagsinput", value: f.object.skill_list.map { |t| t}.join(', ') %>
   ```

which generates the following html code:

[image]

**Thanks a lot**

Fabrizio Bertoglio

Comment: your question doesn't make sense, and what's with the first paragraph?

Comment: @madalin ivascu Ok, I removed it.  I am trying to improve also the other points of the question.

Comment: how do you call this plugin?, are data.holder and data dynamically added elements ?

Comment: did you wrap your code in a document ready statement?

Comment: @madalin ivascu for you first question I added point 3 to my post, while for the document ready statement. I just added the jquery file to my html document, following the Ruby on Rails conventions for adding javascript assets files. The functions in jquery.tagsinput are not included in a document ready statement, it looks like the trigger is inside jquery.js (point 2)
I did not write any custom js code.

Comment: @madalin I will test by modifing the jquery.tagsinput file with a document ready statement compatible with rails turbolinks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135994/discussion-between-fabrizio-bertoglio-and-madalin-ivascu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my `application.js`, it includes the following files:

```
//= require jquery.tagsinput
//= require form-component
//= require scripts
```

Jquery.tagsinput does not have a ready function, but the script.js function does and I the problem started when I edited the script.js ready function.

`script.js` has the following code:

```
function initializeJS() {
     // Some js code
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    initializeJS();
});
```

The problem could have been caused by the editing I have done of the `script.js` ready function to be compatible with the `turbolinks` gem (instead of using `.save` i would use `.on('turbolinks:load'..`)

```
jQuery(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
    initializeJS();
});
```

Once i corrected that line, the problem was remove, but I do not have understanding of the real reason it has been fixed. I did not disable turbolinks. I will in the future try to understand the real reason and post an explanation.